# JSON record manually creaed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create the following record in JS as a string to pass to DataTables. The example below is failing. What do I need to change. Thank you.

**RECORD:**

```
{
 "SMG": "<input type="hidden" class="smg-wty-up-val" value="none">SMG Standard Warranty Only", 
 "wty": "' + StdWty + '",        <== VARIABLE HERE
 "pri": "0.00" 
};
```

**TRYING THIS (AMONGST OTHER COMBINATIONS):**

```
WtyRow +='{ \
            \"SMG\": "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"smg-wty-up-val\" value=\"none\">SMG Standard Warranty Only\", \
            \"wty\": \"' + StdWty + '\", \
            \"pri\": \"0.00\" \
          }';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with double quotes, then use single quotes inside the string, and vice versa. Try

```
var obj = {
           "SMG": "<input type='hidden' class='smg-wty-up-val' value='none'>SMG Standard Warranty Only",
           "wty": StdWty,
           "pri": "0.00"
          };
```

You can stringify the above like `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: Hi @TJ the challenge is still how to enclose the whole string in quotes too... thanks for pointing out stringfy... I think this will do it